# How do I use boost lambda's to call a method on each element in a collection?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, lambda

I have a list of `shared_ptr`s to observer instances. I would like to use boost lambdas to call the notify method on each observer, like so:

```
list<ObserverSharedPtr> observers;
...
for_each(observers.begin(), observers.end(), _1->notify(event));
```

However, the above code yields the following compilation error:

```
error: base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `boost::arg<1>'
```

My question is, how do I utilize boost lambdas to call a method on each element in a STL collection?

Comment: why do you (or anybody) want to use boost lambdas ??? Just use C++ lambdas, they're part of the standard.

Comment: @Walter I'm not using c++11

Comment: You have to use `boost::bind`.

Comment: @MM. I noticed, but I fail to understand why. I also fail to understand why current compilers still use an >10 year old standard, i.e. why `-std=c++11` is not the default.

Comment: @Walter maybe because the "current compilers" still do not implement c++11 well enough? E.g., take a look at the feature set of msvc11 (not speaking of msvc10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `boost::bind` or `boost::lambda::bind`:

```
for_each(observers.begin(), observers.end(), boost::bind(&Observer::notify, _1, event));
```